make build and install for each sub-target together
I have a main Makefile which builds multiple sub-targets(in a proper dependency order) For eg. lib1.so, lib2.so, lib3.so which depends on lib1.so, lib4.so which depends on lib2.so. After the build process, I install all the sub-targets to a lib search directory from the build sub-directories of each sub-target being built, so that they can loaded from this path which is known to dynamic linker during building and execution of main binary target. As of now I'm building all the sub-targets initially and then installing them. Instead I would like to know how to perform build and install together for each sub-target.
make // build all sub-targets
make install // install to lib search directory which is known to dynamic linker

make // for binary. which uses lib search directory for linking and loading all the .so files


Typically the install target would depend on the build target, because you can't install until after you've built.  So if you just run the install target it will do both at the same time.

"After the build process, I install all the sub-targets to a lib search directory [...] so that they can loaded from this path [...] during building" -- you can do that, but it's a pain, and not conventional.  The idiomatic approach is to build everything and then install everything.  That is supported in part by using appropriate -L options to tell the linker where to find any as-yet uninstalled libraries.
